# Livewire component shows its own code but doesn't render

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-jetstream

I'm using Laravel Jetstream with Livewire. I'm trying to make my own Livewire component according the docs:

`php artisan livewire:make my_component`

By default it locates in `resources/views/livewire/my-component.blade.php`. I added this string to `resources/views/profile/show.blade.php` file: `@livewire('my-component')`. I want to see this component in user profile page.

But instead of the component I only see the its code on the page.[image]

In this picture I added my component instead of `two-factor-authentication-form.blade.php`. Here is the code of `resources/views/liwevire/my-component.blade.php`:

```
<x-jet-action-section>
    <x-slot name="title">
        {{ __('Two Factor Authentication') }}
    </x-slot>

    <x-slot name="description">
        {{ __('Add additional security to your account using two factor authentication.') }}
    </x-slot>

    <x-slot name="content">
        Some content
    </x-slot>

</x-jet-action-section>
```

Here is the piece of code of `resources/views/profile/show.blade.php`:

```
@if (Laravel\Fortify\Features::canManageTwoFactorAuthentication())
    <div class="mt-10 sm:mt-0">
        <!-- @livewire('profile.two-factor-authentication-form') -->
        @livewire('my-component')
    </div>
    <x-jet-section-border />
@endif
```

How can I fix it?

P. S. I have removed comment line from `resources/views/profile/show.blade.php` but still nothing. Here is the code:

```
@if (Laravel\Fortify\Features::canManageTwoFactorAuthentication())
    <div class="mt-10 sm:mt-0">
        @livewire('my-component')
    </div>
    <x-jet-section-border />
@endif
```

And the result:
[image]

P.P.S. Here is the code of `app/Http/Livewire/MyComponent`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class MyComponent extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.my-component');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try removing <!-- @livewire('profile.two-factor-authentication-form') --> from the code and seeing if that helps. Maybe it's commenting out some of the content partially??

Comment: @brett I have tried but still nothing.

Comment: "_liwevire_" in your paths is a typo I guess?

Comment: You can see in your screenshot it still has --> So when you comment stuff out, don't use HTML comments, use blade comments {{-- this is commented out  --}}

Comment: @brombeer sure, have fixed it

Comment: Can you update the my-component with the latest code you are trying please

Comment: @x1netta The screenshot should have changed too now, can you update that

Comment: Remove the comment in your code.

Comment: Does your component work on a page other than `show.blade.php`? Can you post the code before `@if (Laravel\Fortify\Features::canManageTwoFactorAuthentication())` there might be something wrong there. Have you made sure that the file exists and is actually named `my_component.blade.php`. Have you tried to alter its content to some simple text only?

Comment: @Brett have a look

Comment: Have you created the matching Class file

From doucmentation - Two new files were created in your project:

app/Http/Livewire/ShowPosts.php
resources/views/livewire/show-posts.blade.php

Comment: @brett you mean component class? Sure, I have. It in `app/Http/Livewire/MyComponent.php`.  It is automatically created after using the command `php artisan livewire:make my_component`.

Comment: @x1netta can you post that code too please! thanks

Comment: @Brett have a look again please

Comment: @x1netta i am stumped. Are you using Livewire 1 or 2

Comment: @Brett according to `composer.json`:  `"livewire/livewire": "^2.5"`

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when using HTML comments to comment out blade rendered components as it still renders the blade component in between the comments

```
<!-- @livewire('profile.two-factor-authentication-form') -->
```

use {{-- --}}

```
{{-- @livewire('profile.two-factor-authentication-form') --}}
```

Comment: It still shouldn't show anything because it's a HTML comment, right?

Comment: @brombeer it shouldn't UNLESS the component renders a closing html comment tag which would then cause it to cancel the comment early

Comment: Which it doesn't seem to do. And `{{ __('Two Factor Authentication') }}` appearing on the page looks like it doesn't even get parsed by Blade